# Google API Find document shared with current user

Tags: javascript, api, google-sheets, google-api

I've been wondering, is there any way to get documents shared with user with google api client for JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I just missed out that google drive api exists which fulfill my need completely (including documents metadata collection). Just go to https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list and check it out